# Is there a way to turn off suggestion popup when opening string in VS Code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, intellisense

I am trying to disable a VS Code pop-up whenever I hit a quotes key (either ' or ", either open or closing). A screenshot is attached of the pop-up. I've been googling my heart out for this but can't seem to find what is driving this behaviour.

Things I've tried:

- Set `"editor.parameterHints.enabled":false` to prevent annoying popups when I enter a function.
- Set `"editor.quickSuggestions": {"other": false, "comments": false, "strings": false}`
- Set `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"` just in case that was doing anything

The same behaviour is not replicated in a new workbook before running any cells, nor in a blank .py file. Files in the same directory are listed, which makes me think that at least part of the popup is coming from the file list. But the others really don't seem meaningful to me.

It ends up costing me a fairly large amount of keystrokes hitting `esc` every time, or going back to correct errors when I hit tab or enter before escaping. And is also just generally annoying. Any help would be appreciated.

Example image of pop-up:
[image: Example image of pop-up]

EDIT:
The list of extensions I am currently working with excluding themes.
I have turned of all except those necessary for Jupyter Notebooks and still get the same behaviour:

- `adam-watters.vscode-color-pick`
- `AndersEAndersen.html-class-suggestions`
- `christian-kohler.path-intellisense`
- `formulahendry.auto-close-tag`
- `formulahendry.auto-rename-tag`
- `hediet.vscode-drawio kiteco.kite`
- `ms-python.python`
- `ms-python.vscode-pylance`
- `ms-toolsai.jupyter`
- `ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap`
- `ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers`
- `ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl`
- `njpwerner.autodocstring`
- `ritwickdey.LiveServer`
- `Shan.code-settings-sync`
- `streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker`
- `WakaTime.vscode-wakatime`
- `wmaurer.change-case`

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: I was going to list them all, but I assume the suggestion is going to be try turning them off to see what is doing it. I will get back to you once I have tried disabling them one by one.

Comment: @Jared It seems has no configuration can do it for now, could you just ignore it? I have submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7925) for it.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Thanks, I guess that I have to. I am loving everything else in VS Code. Just this one thing is bothering me. Hope I don't wear out my Escape key by the time it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This solved it for me: In VSCode settings, go to 'Extensions > Jupyter > Python Completion Trigger Characters'

Defaults were: .%'"

So I deleted the single and double quotes, restarted, and voila, no more annoying popups.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).